# How to detect source presence using LTC4412?

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, linear

[image: LTC4412 IC (Linear Technology)]

I'm using 2 power sources as shown in below picture. The status pin is suggested to pull HIGH to VCC(which can be the adapter input). As mentioned that Status pin OUTPUT is LOW when Wall adapter present, but the actual voltage I'm getting is 6.8V and when only battery(7.4v) is present the voltage is 7.2V. So how can I detect source presence using LTC4412. Kindly help regarding this issue.

Comment: Where precisely is the pull-up resistor supplied from? Also, are your given measurements the STATUS pin voltages for each case, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the measurements are of STAT pin. The resistor is pulled up with wall adapter input line(12V)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the LTC4412 output for pulling up the STAT line instead?

Comment: If not pulling up the pin, voltage is 0V when both battery and 12V sources are present and 1.8v-2.2v when only battery is present. So a little confusion is there

Comment: The stat pin is an open collector which does not pull HIGH. So, when a wall adapter is present, the pin is 0V. When no wall adapter is present, the output is open. But, because there is no wall adapter to pull up the voltage, the voltage is still 0V or some weird value. You should connect

Comment: You should pull up to the "TO LOAD" somehow. If correct the "TO LOAD" is or generates the "Vcc".

Comment: > The STAT pin will then go from an open state to a 10μA current sink ... what resistor did you use? 470k? Better reapply Ohm's law.

Comment: Thank you, the connection worked fine by pulling up the resistor to LOAD/VCC. The voltage level of status pin is changing accordingly. But according to my question can you please explain why it is giving such voltage levels, as per my previous connection(status pin pulled up to 12V)

Comment: When there is a wall adapter present and the pull up of 470k were connected to this voltage, the open collector would draw 10uA, so there would be a 4.7V voltage drop across the resistor. 12V-4.7V=7.3V .. your reading was 6.8V Maybe the 12V was 11.5V or the sink current deviated...

Comment: Without wall adapter the STAT pin will be floating. It is not clearly connected to anything, but likely internally still connected in high resistive and capacitve way to "something". When you measure this floating pin, you would read a "undefined" voltage.

Comment: Yes, the input is not exactly 12v the diode drops to 11.5V, I guess the open collector pin doesn't sink current while battery source is present and the "undefined" voltage may be the battery voltage(7.2V).